# VS 2010 Video Card switching

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gpu, switching

I have together an Intel(R) HD Graphics and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660.

Now I am writing an OpenGL aplication in Visual Studio 2010. By checking the OpenGL version, it results OpenGL 3.3, so I think it`s running on the HD Graphics.

I would appreciate if someone could tell me how can I change it.

Comment: Which monitor is set as your "Primary Display" ?

Comment: Hey, thanks :) 
I found the error. Monitor was connected to the Intel VC.